# Groovy socket not working in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a small Groovy script which connect to a TCP server on my PC (Windows 10)

```
def Socket socket;
def OutputStream output;
println("Try to connect to 127.0.0.1:4444")
socket = new Socket( "127.0.0.1", 4444);
socket.setSoTimeout(3000);
output = socket.getOutputStream();
```

If I run this script on freestyle project with execute Groovy script build option

[image]

everything work fine and I connect success to my server. But If I integrate this script into a pipeline

[image]

the connection is refused! (even with sandbox deactivated)

```
Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
Pipeline] node
unning on LaptopLolo in c:\WK_jenkins\workspace\FolderLOLO\CallGRoovyScript
Pipeline] {
Pipeline] stage
Pipeline] { (Example Build)
Pipeline] script
Pipeline] {
Pipeline] echo
ODE_NAME = LaptopLolo
Pipeline] echo
ry to connect to 127.0.0.1:4444
Pipeline] }
Pipeline] // script
Pipeline] }
Pipeline] // stage
Pipeline] }
Pipeline] // node
Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ava.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.constructorCall(DefaultInvoker.java:25)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:17)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:97)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor462.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Well the Jenkins groovy interpreter has various (and not always obvious) restrictions but to do something as simple as an HTTP(S) or TCP connection, you can always use an `sh` script and use `curl` or `wget` (or `bat` and their equivalent on Windows), or use the widely used [HttpRequest plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/) for something like:

```
echo "Trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:4444"
def response = httpRequest 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/'
echo "Status: "+response.status
echo "Content: "+response.content
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my server is a pure TCP (no http inside). And i preferer to avoid any os specific command. In fact i am really frustrating to have something working on freestyle pipeline and not on pipeline. After few tests it seems that the socket is open on the master when run it on pipeline even if agent is assign

Comment: Yes, the pipeline Groovy code ALWAYS executes on the master, so this is totally expected. When using `sh` or `bat`, which are built-in DSL commands that must be enclosed in a `node` (or agent definition), then these commands will execute on the agent instead. With a similar approach, you could use `node() { sh "groovy abc.groovy" }` to execute groovy code on the agent, but you'll need a `sh` or `bat` command...